# Swift: Is there a way I could define I only need to implement either one function in a protocol?

Tags: swift

Assuming we have a protocol with two possible configuration functions. But one and only one of them is required for any of its implementor.

```
public protocol Car {
  associatedtype T

  func configure(with model: T, engine: EngineType)
  func configure(with model: T)
}
```

With the above, I'll need to implement both. Is there a way I could make it required only to implement one of it?

Comment: Why not require just the first and let the implementer use a default value for the second parameter? You could even provide that in a protocol extension.

Comment: Maybe you can also provide default implementations to both methods. I know this would make both optional for implementers, but then they would implement only the one they need.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the protocol with only one function and with an optional `EngineType`. Then always implement it with a default value. This way both `myCar.configure(with:)` and `myCar.configure(with:engine:)` can be called.

```
protocol Car {
    associatedtype T

    func configure(with model: T, engine: EngineType?)
}


class MyCar : Car {
    typealias T = Int

    func configure(with model: Int, engine: EngineType? = nil) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the approach I thought. But was thinking if there's something better. Imagine if we have two function that doesn't have the same parameter, then we might need to make both as optional. But I upvote this as it is one possible approach. Will see if there's other answer before I select this as THE ANSWER. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    @objc optional func maybeDoSomething()
    func mustDoSomething()
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
    func mustDoSomething() {

    }
// No need to implement maybeDoSomething() method
}
```

Another way is

```
protocol MySwiftProtocol {
    func implementThisMethod()
    func mayNotImplementThisMethod()
}

extension MySwiftProtocol {
    func mayNotImplementThisMethod() {
        //Nothing to do here
    }
}

class MySwiftClass:MySwiftProtocol {
    func implementThisMethod() {
        //This has to be implemented
    }
//No need to implement mayNotImplementThisMethod() method

}
```

Comment: This will force `implementThisMethod()` as the one to be implemented. What I want is, the implementor can choose implement `mayNotImplementThisMethod()`, then doesn't need to implement `implementThisMethod()`, or vice versa.